# How to only remove the numbers that are before a string and not after? (inside data frame)

Tags: python, string, dataframe

I have a data frame looking like this:

```
Col1
123/ House Number 5
345/ House Number 10
678/ House Number 15
```

I want to delete the numeric value before the string but not the value after the string (you may assume they are all in the format shown in the example of number followed by a dash).

i am using the following code but it removes all numeric characters regardless of the position:

```
df['Col1'] = df['Col1'].str.replace('\d+', '')
```

Is there a way to remove only the numbers before the string?

Answer (score 1):

With `^` you tell the regex to start at the beginning of a line. Try changing the pattern to `'^\d+'`

```
df['Col1'] = df['Col1'].str.replace('^\d+', '')
```

Comment: I found another answer, but yours works best for cells that don't start with numbers (mine deletes the first character of those) and this one also gets rid of the dash. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The reason your pattern `'^\d*\S'` deletes the first character is that the `*` represents 0 or more whereas the `+` in this `^\d+` pattern means one or more. Hence in this pattern, will only match if the line begins with at least 1 digit. The next part of your pattern `\S` means not whitespace and hence the backslash is deleted or anything before it that is not whitespace. Also, it is worth noting that it will only remove 1 of these characters. If you wanted to delete the backslash and white space I would suggest using the pattern I commented on your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found this website in an earlier question and got this format:

```
df['Col1'] = df['Col1'].str.replace('^\d*\S', '')
```

Basically starts at the start of the line and takes into account the non-white Space that is the dash. You can try different regex types in this website:

https://regex101.com/r/B7DbxW/1

EDIT: and to delete the extra spaces left in the start of the cell:

```
df['Col1'] = df['Col1'].str.replace('^\s*','')
```

Comment: Just to quickly point out you can achieve all of this in a single pattern; `'^\d+\/\s*'`